# Sending Broadcast Receiver from IntentService to Fragment (Activity)

Tags: android, fragment, intentservice

I have a problem when I send an Broadcast Receiver from IntentService to Fragment (Activity).

I have an application with two types of process:
[image]

The first process have MainActivity and MainFragment. At this fragment, I implemented like that:

```
private void registerStickerReload() {
    mStickerReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals(DataFetcherService.ACTION_RELOAD_STICKER)) {
                // Some code here
            }
        }
    };
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(
            DataFetcherService.ACTION_RELOAD_STICKER);
    mLocalBroadcastManager.registerReceiver(mStickerReceiver, intentFilter);
}
```

and:

```
private void unregisterStickerReload() {
    if (mLocalBroadcastManager != null) {
        mLocalBroadcastManager.unregisterReceiver(mStickerReceiver);
    }
}
```

I register receiver from onStart() and unregister from onStop().
From the second process, I run DataFetcherService class like IntentService.
[image]

My code here:

```
private class BasicLoader extends AsyncTask<Request, Void, Response> {
    public BasicLoader() {
    }

    @Override
    protected Response doInBackground(Request... params) {
        Request request = params[0];
        Response response = request.execute();
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_RELOAD_STICKER);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                        .sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
        });
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Response result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

I debugged and the LocalBroadcastManager sent the Broadcast but it don't have any action to onReceive(Context, Intent).

Here's some cases I tried:

- Remove Handler.
- Remove Looper.getMainLooper().
- Remove unregisterStickerReload().

But It's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) class overview:

> Helper to register for and send broadcasts of Intents to local objects
>   within your process.

Because `DataFetcherService` service is running in separate process from `datafetcher` and activity `MainFragment` is running in different process.that's why onReceive method is not called when sending Broadcast from  `doInBackground` method.

To receive and send Broadcast between different process or applications use [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's working now. So my problem here is I want to keep both `DataFetcherService` run in different process with `MainFragment` and `LocalBroadcastManager`. Do you have any suggest for me?
Thanks